# SSRS line chart with custom x axis categories

Tags: reporting-services, linechart

Alright, this is kind of a convoluted problem, so bear with me:

I have a chart that displays 25 hours worth of data from rows sent to it. The hours of the data are to be displayed starting and ending with the 22nd hour. That is, the x axis goes 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, ... 22. It's important to note that there are two 22nd hours on two separate days.

Now, it is possible that the database will not return some rows. In which case, there must be an empty space for that hour. However, there must still be 25 x axis values.

This combination of restrictions has me stumped. I can't represent the x axis as a custom scalar, because the values are to be displayed out of order and duplicated. And I can't find a way to use an x axis category because I won't get all of the categories from the data and, again, there is a duplicated 22nd hour.

Any help is appreciated, let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column to the dataset to calculate a "relative hour".  This would start with a value of 0 for the 22nd hour, 1 for the 23rd etc finishing with 25 for the 2nd 22nd hour.

Then I would change the Category Group definition in the Chart to use that "relative hour" value as the "Group On" value.  Note the Label can remain as is.

I would change the source dataset so that it always returns a row for all the 25 x axis values, e.g. via a right join to a numbers table. Rows representing those "missing" hours will need both the "relative hour" value and your existing hour column value for the label.